# AWS ELB – Insecure Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb

I'm attempting to have my client communicate to an Elastic Load Balancer, listening on port 443 and using an SSL certificate associated with `*.mywebsite.com`.

The origin for the requests is `app.mywebsite.com` and I'm sending requests directly to the load balancer (`https://myapp-000000000.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/register`), but Chrome is logging `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`.

In my security tab, I'm seeing `No security details are available for this origin.` associated with the requests I'm making to the ELB.

Is there something I'm missing about the SSL setup that is causing my ELB to not return security details?

EDIT: I should mention that my static app is hosted on firebase.

Comment: How are you sending requests from `app.mywebsite.com` to your ELB? The recommended way is having a Route 53 record set as an alias to your ELB. Is that what you have?

Comment: I've hardcoded the elb dns into my app. No route 53 aliasing, which I recognize will need to be done. Could this be causing an SSL issue?

Comment: You don't need a Route53 Alias if the load balancer isn't serving the apex domain.

Comment: So your app (JavaScript?) actually requests the ELB hostname? That's your problem right there. The requested host needs to match the certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You associated an SSL certificate like `*.mywebsite.com` with the load balancer, but as of yet you are not using your domain name with the load balancer. The SSL certificate will only work when the domain name matches the certificate.

Right now you are still sending requests to `https://myapp-000000000.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/register`, but the SSL certificate is not for the elb.amazonaws.com domain name. You need to point a DNS record to the ELB, like `api.mywebsite.com` via a CNAME record in your DNS host.

After you do that you need to make sure you send traffic to the ELB like this: `https://api.mywebsite.com/api/register`

Comment: Thanks. I made the change you mentioned but I'm still receiving the insecure response error despite the correct routing of the request.

Comment: If you load the API URL directly in your browser, you get an insecure warning? Does the domain name change in the URL in your browser when it loads?

Comment: Ah - I was unaware that multi level subdomains weren't possible. E.g. a certificate for `*.mysite.com` isn't a valid certificate for `api.app.mysite.com`. I created a certificate specifically for the API subdomain, which did the charm. Thank you!